# Permission denied to access the file from php script

Tags: php, exec

I have shared library file client.so. Which works fine in command line. I am trying to run it using exec().

client takes one string argument as a input. like ./client "this is nice"
code is:

```
 $s="hello"; 
 escapeshellarg($s); 
 $a=exec('/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket "./client $s"');
```

also

```
 $a=exec('/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket "./client "Nice bad" "');
```

It gives error:

```
sh: 1: /home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket: Permission denied
```

I tried changing the chmod all I found on web and other relevant changes. But no change. Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Comment: You have to appropriately `chmod`/`chown` *all* the components of the path. "Permission denied" is pretty clear.

Comment: not sure but try these. `$a=exec('/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket ./client '.$s);` , `$a=exec('/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket ./client "Nice bad" '); `

Comment: @user174889: To some group that your web server user is part of.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks for your help,  I applied permission and made one change in command that I was executing. That solved my issue. Vote my next answer if you like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting the permission execute in following manner will solve the problem:

```
$a=exec('/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/client "critic good"');
```

client is the executable file that I wanted to execute and "critic good" is argument to be passed!