# FreeBSD PHP exec permission denied

Tags: php, python, linux

I want to run a couple of Python scripts from PHP.

On an Ubuntu machine everything looks good right out of the box.

On FreeBSD though I get `/usr/local/lib/python2.7: Permission denied`

Any idea how to give permissions to Apache to run a Python through `shell_exec` or `exec` ?

Also see how I had to name the full path of the Python ?
Is there any way to avoid that too ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513216/permission-denied-to-access-the-file-from-php-script or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236091/php-exec-command-permission-denied or http://serverfault.com/questions/667663/permission-denied-when-script-tries-to-run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to use full paths for both python and your script.
`$foo = exec('/usr/bin/python /path/script.py');`

Also, make sure the file permissions where your script is located can be accessed by www, probably will need to `chmod 755 /path`.

Comment: The folder which has the files is 755 all the way to the scripts. Did a `sys.path` from the cmd and the path is `/usr/local/lib/python2.7`.
I am also using the full path to the script

Comment: Do a `which python2.7`, that's where your python binary is kept. `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` is a directory for python libraries. `sys.path` gives a list of locations that specify the search path for modules.

Comment: `which python2.7` gave the correct path, used that and it works. Thank you